# Appropriate way to reject creation of a collection item in firestore, when parent collection doesn't exist?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an `onRequest` cloud function which inserts an item into my firestore instance:

```js
...
db.collection('game').doc(game_id).collection('board').doc(board_id).add(new_piece)
...
```

If `game_id` doesn't exist in my database, the doc `new_piece` is still inserted, presumably under orphaned `game` and `board` collections (they show up italicized and slightly faded in firestore console).

This seems to be standard behavior. However, if I want to reject creation of documents if their parent path doesn't exist, what is the best way to do so?

One obvious way is to first check the existence of `game` and `board` collections. However, that adds additional latency and more `.then` blocks (I don't want to think in terms of monads here!). Is this the recommended way?

Is there a way I can simply instruct firestore to not create orphaned docs and collections in a given insert path and return an error (to be handled by the caller)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible.  If you want to know if something exists, you will have to make queries for it.